# Looping over requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to loop over a website with a text file but it seems that it gets passed a list instead of a value.
I am opening a file, and then passing the values from that file to requests so it can return if the domain exists or not. I seem to be getting 404's but my output looks like this:

```
[-] Not found! http://10.xx.xx.xxx/['.bash_history'] 404
[-] Not found! http://10.xx.xx.xxx/['.bashrc'] 404
[-] Not found! http://10.xx.xx.xxx/['.cache'] 404
[-] Not found! http://10.xx.xx.xxx/['.config'] 404
[-] Not found! http://10.xx.xx.xxx/['.cvs'] 404
```

I can tell that my `wordlist` is being passed through but it is passed through as a list.
Also here is my `main()` code:

```
    try:
    with open(wordlist, 'r+') as file:
        for r in file:
            word = r.split()
            domain = url + (str(word).lower())
            r = requests.get(domain)
            # print(r, str(word))
            if (r.status_code == 200):
                print('[+++] ' + domain)
            else:
                print('[-] Not found!', domain, r.status_code)
                pass
        
    except InvalidURL as e:
        print('Invalid URL')
```

If I remove the `str()` function from word: `domain = url + word`

I get an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Answer (score 1):

`r.split()` returns a list of strings from each line in your file. Without seeing the contents of your word list, I can't be sure, but what you probably want to do is iterate over all the strings returned by `r.split()`.

```
  for r in file:
        for word in r.split():
            domain = url + word.lower()
```

Comment: I do want to iterate over each word in that file. I have used 'r' to iterate over the wordlist and it seems to do the job correctly!